# WebSockets server: reading data after handshake

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

I've managed to get the socket opened, hands shaken, and even though that's all fun and so, I would like to handle the data itself now. The small thingy is that unlike the HTTP headers which are pure ascii, the content seems to be encoded:

```
ÅÅúÅ à›ÅÅ»öë∑âÅÅ«∆{UÅÅeæƒ$ÅÅvü
‡7ÅÅŸJêÏòÅÅ~}Z¥?ÅÅ9TÉHxÅÅ[ 1†ÅÅs    óE2ÅÅ9\ÅyxÅÅ#´°ºbÅÅïôx ‘ÅÅ)Ÿ1–hÅÅ⁄}
```

That's what server received from Google Chrome client's

```
socket.send("A");
socket.send("A");
```

Just skimming the protocol definition, I didn't find anything about encoding besides base64, which this clearly isn't.

How should I handle the content serverside?

Edit: already looked quite a few articles, but nearly all are about the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data that is sent from the client to the server is masked (to protect misbehaving intermediaries from getting confused). It's a 4 byte running XOR with the mask sent as the first 4 bytes of the payload. It is described in the [spec in section 5.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17#section-5.3)

Comment: Thanks. That might have been it, but the mask bit is actually zero. For the time being, I will use *jetty*.

Comment: @MikulasDite, I think you are misinterpreting which bit is the mask bit. Unmasked data sent from the client to server is prohibited by the specification (such that the server is required to immediately close the connection if it receives an unmasked frame). I've also used most Chrome versions which implemente the newer spec versions (HyBi) and have never seen unmasked data from browser to server.

Comment: oh, that would actually explain everything. Thanks, I suppose that's that.